# Return a string with dash '-' marks before and after each odd integer

Tags: javascript

Learning Javscript.

Kata description is as follows...

Given a number, return a string with dash'-'marks before and after each odd integer, but do not begin or end the string with a dash mark.

Link = https://www.codewars.com/kata/dashatize-it/train/javascript

Current Code :

```
    function dashatize(num) {

  var numP = Math.abs(num) + '';
  var result = [numP[0]];
  while (numP > 0) {
    for (var x = 1; x < numP.length; x++) {
        result.push('-', numP[x]);

    }
    return result.join('');
    }

  return numP;
}
```

Test Cases :

```
  Test.describe("Basic", function(){
  Test.assertEquals(dashatize(274), "2-7-4", "Should return 2-7-4");
  Test.assertEquals(dashatize(5311), "5-3-1-1", "Should return 5-3-1-1");
  Test.assertEquals(dashatize(86320), "86-3-20", "Should return 86-3-20");
  Test.assertEquals(dashatize(974302), "9-7-4-3-02", "Should return 9-7-4-3-02");
});
Test.describe("Weird", function(){
  Test.assertEquals(dashatize(NaN), "NaN", "Should return NaN");
  Test.assertEquals(dashatize(0), "0", "Should return 0");
  Test.assertEquals(dashatize(-1), "1", "Should return 1");
  Test.assertEquals(dashatize(-28369), "28-3-6-9", "Should return 28-3-6-9");
});
```

Question is : How can i refactor this code to not put hyphens with non-odd integers. Thanks

Comment: ```for (var x = 1; x < numP.length; x++) {
        result.push('-', numP[x]);

    }``` - start with that loop - only add the dash to odd numbers.

Comment: thanks, why am i being down voted btw ?

Comment: Probably because you didn't really try anything - and your question looked very copy pasted.

Comment: meh, this is a learning atmosphere, and its my first question. its pretty obvious i started and got stuck and copied my question from the kata i am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution :

```
function dashatize(num) {
    return num.toString().
      replace(/([13579])/g,'-$1-'). // dashes around odd digits
      replace(/\-+/g,'-'). // replace multiple dashes by one dash
      replace(/^\-/,''). // remove starting dash
      replace(/\-$/,''); // remove ending dash
}
```

It could probably be shorter, but at least it is easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to understand the power of regex a bit more. Very concise and easy to read. Would upvote if i could :(

Comment: Could refactor last two lines into .replace(/(^-|-$)/g, '')

Answer (score 0):

A not so readable solution:

```
function dashatize(num) {
      //get 'em
      num = Math.abs(num) + ''
      num = num.split('').map( (char, i, chars) => {
          if( Number(char) != char) return char;
          return Number(char) % 2 !== 0 ? 
             ( Number(chars[i-1]) % 2 === 0 ? '-' + char + '-' : char + '-') : char;
      })
      num = num.join('')
      num = num[num.length-1] === '-' ? num.slice(0,num.length-1) : num;
      return num;
    };
```

You can achieve it more elegantly with `regex` and `replace`